# Django some columns in a model is migrated

Tags: python, django

I have the following model

```
from django.db import models

class Todo(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at_one: models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    finished_at: models.DateField(null=True)
    is_completed: models.BooleanField(default=False)
    list = models.ForeignKey(
        "TodoList", related_name="todos", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class TodoList(models.Model):
    title: models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_at: models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then when I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and  `python3 manage.py migrate`, there is no error. But when I check the tables created, some columns are missing.

I run `.schema app_todo` to check the tables of Todo

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "app_todo" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "content" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "list_id" bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES "app_todolist" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
CREATE INDEX "app_todo_list_id_c59d99ef" ON "app_todo" ("list_id");
```

Only id, content and list_id are created and three columns missing.

For TodoList:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "app_todolist" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);
```

title and create_at are missing.

Please let me know if there is additional information that I should provide.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `=` not `:` to define the fields. Using `:` creates a type annotation it doesn't define the field on the model

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe I made this silly mistake TvT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably made a typo write writing your model. You must not use `:` but `=` when declaring your fields. It should be :

```py
from django.db import models

class Todo(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at_one = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    finished_at = models.DateField(null=True)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    list = models.ForeignKey(
        "TodoList", related_name="todos", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class TodoList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

When using `:` you may create some class attributes but that are not considered by Django for building database models.